# Не могу выйти с Vim

Tags: vim, vi

помогите пожалуйста, при всех моих попытках, когда я пишу в редакторе Vim 
:x или :wq то мне пишет:

[No write since last change]
/bin/bash: wq: command not found

shell returned 127

Press ENTER or type command to continue

И потом, какую клавишу я бы не нажал всеравно меня кидает в Vim, а если закрою окно то изминения не сохраняются. Как исправить

Comment: Можно попробовать выйти, нажатием ZZ (Z 2 раза)

Comment: команды в вопросе правильные. Просто Вы их неправильно вводите. Такое может быть, если вначале набрали восклицательный знак (я не знаю почему, может раскладка такая). Убедитесь, что Вы вводите правильные символы.

Comment: Да я ставлю восклицательные знаки ибо мне пишет

Comment: `readonly` option is set ( add ! to override )

Comment: вот, а в вопросе о нем - ни слова. восклицательный знак нужно в самый конец добавлять :wq!  Если же файл сильно "только для чтения", тогда :q! и уже снимать с него признаки только для чтения

Comment: А как снять признаки только для чтения, просто вчера начал пользоваться

Comment: а тут надо разбираться. Может файл доступен на запись только руту, а Вы зашли с под обычного пользователя. А может файл находится на компакт диске. И тут уже немного сложнее.

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать ваш коментарий ответом к вопросу?

Comment: I have been using vim for two years mostly because I can't quit. ©

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270/5430535 - 2 ляма просмотров.